# $L_1$ and $L_2$ are regular and we have a new language $\text{pref}(L_1,L_2) = \{x \in \Sigma^* \mid \exists u \in L_2\text{ s.t. }xu\in L_1\}$

Tags: automata, regular-language

1. prove that $\operatorname{pref}(L_1,L_2) = \{x \in \Sigma^* \mid \exists u \in L_2 \text{ such that $xu\in L_1$}\}$ is regular.

So I was thinking proving this question by building an automata for pref but couldn't do it really much.
than using closure properties but I couldn't really think of any that will help aside of a homomorphic function which I don't know how to build.

2. prove or disprove that if only $L_1$ is regular than pref is regular

Here again using closure properties but cant really think of any.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is true for all languages $L_2$, regular or not. Recall that if $L$ is a language and $u$ is a word,
$$
Lu^{-1} = \{v \in \Sigma^* \mid vu \in L\}.
$$
**Hint**. Use the fact that, for every regular language $L$, there are only finitely many distinct languages of the form $Lu^{-1}$, all of them regular.

**Hint 2**.
$$
\operatorname{pref}(L_1,L_2) = \bigcup_{u \in L_2}Lu^{-1}
$$

Comment: I really try to think hard about it but I cant really have it. can I have maybe another hint?

Comment: @dani I gave you another hint.

Comment: so now I understand why I could not have got this with those hints, it because we did not learned this definition (Lu^(-1)), I do understand it but I cant use it. I was thinking maybe proving that if L1 is regular than pref(L1) is regular and then I can just say that pref(L1,L2) is already included in pref(L1) and to be done with it.

Comment: Are you aware of the [Myhill-Nerode theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill–Nerode_theorem) ? Hint 1 is just the dual version of it, with left derivatives replaced by right derivatives.

Comment: yes I am aware of it and I know that the theorem says that if L is regular than it have a finite number of Equivalence classes. Is every Lu^(-1) is an Equivalence class?

Comment: First of all, I would like to apologise: there was a typo in my answer (in the definition of $Lu^{-1}$), now corrected. The Nerode equivalence $\sim_L$ can be defined by $u \sim_L v$ if and only if $u^{-1}L = v^{-1}L$, where $u^{-1}L = \{w \in \Sigma^* \mid uw \in L\}$. This is better explained on the French version of the wikipedia entry [Théorème de Myhill-Nerode](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Théorème_de_Myhill-Nerode).